# RenderScript support library V8 fail to compile

Tags: android, android-support-library, renderscript

My platform information
OS: Windows 7 32 bit
ADT version: Build: v22.2.1-833290
SDK Tools version: 22.2.1
SDK Built-tools version: 18.1

I was trying to get the new Renderscript support library v8 to work. I created an android application using API level 18 as the target SDK and compile SDK, API level 17 as the minimum required SDK. I then followed the steps in the following links to configure my project, http://android-developers.blogspot.hk/2013/09/renderscript-in-android-support-library.html ,  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis .

After I added

```
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=18.1.0
```

into the file "project.properties", I added an empty .rs file into the src folder (under my package, just like usual). Then I received the following error message.

```
[2013-09-22 22:32:32 - aaaaa] <invalid>: error: missing pragma for version in source file
[2013-09-22 22:32:32 - aaaaa] <invalid>: error: missing "#pragma rs java_package_name(com.foo.bar)" in source file
[2013-09-22 22:32:32 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\armeabi-v7a\test.o: attempt to map 40 bytes at offset 1616 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
[2013-09-22 22:32:32 - aaaaa] C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\mips\test.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
[2013-09-22 22:32:32 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\x86\test.o: section name section has wrong type: 2097152
[2013-09-22 22:32:32 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\x86\test.o: attempt to map 46661632 bytes at offset 0 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
```

Since I understand the meaning of the first two error message, I added

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.aaaaa)
```

to the file.

While the first two error message went away, the following error message appeared again and I can't get rid of it by adding/modifying the content of the script (e.g. I copied a previously working script and it won't work now). However, I observed that the corresponding .java script file in the gen folder was created properly (with import android.support.v8.renderscript.*; inside).

```
[2013-09-22 22:34:29 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\armeabi-v7a\test.o: attempt to map 40 bytes at offset 1616 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\mips\test.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\x86\test.o: section name section has wrong type: 2097152
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\x86\test.o: attempt to map 46661632 bytes at offset 0 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\armeabi-v7a\test2.o: section name section has wrong type: 469762048
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\armeabi-v7a\test2.o: attempt to map 3103784960 bytes at offset 0 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\mips\test2.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\x86\test2.o: section name section has wrong type: 7168
[2013-09-22 22:34:30 - aaaaa] C:\Work\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\i686-linux-android-ld.exe: fatal error: C:\Users\rensijie\workspace\aaaaa\bin\rsObj\x86\test2.o: attempt to map 39168 bytes at offset 0 exceeds size of file; the file may be corrupt
```

In eclipse, there's a red cross on the project name, indicating there's something wrong in the project. If I try to run the application, eclipse will prompt "Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application". However, other than the error message I got, and the red cross on the project name, there's no error in any of the java file (no red crosses on the java files)

Comment: Can you try deleting those temporary files in rsObj? The error messages you wrote above are complaining about them, and it is possible they are leftover from a bad compile before. Alternatively, just start a new project and add the proper .rs file (with pragmas) to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried and it didn't work. Same error message will occur.

Comment: A follow up, I tried on Windows 7 both 32bit and 64 bit, Windows XP and Windows 8 64bit. All same issue.

Comment: And if I "just start a new project and add the proper .rs file (with pragmas) to it." the complain on the "missing pragma" will disappear, however, the the error on the .o files still exist. The whole project won't run. Deletion of the .o files won't work.

Comment: we fixed the bug internally, and we should have a new SDK package up in the next few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was addressed by people in Google very recently. See  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60327&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&start=200